# Linq Method Syntax - Can not convert IQueryable to Bool

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I try to re-factor query 1 to query 2 syntax... because of more more readable etc. 
paramaters like "group, begindate, enddate and excludeManifestatie are passed via argument (method parms).. I check whether they are blank or not )passed or not so I can built my dynamic Linq SQL.

But I get error in Query 1 when I use ....HasValue check. It says: 
**"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'bool'"**

Query 2 works fine and that's what I want, but it has complicated syntax, so I need to correct Query 1 syntax.

**QUERY 1:**

```
((String.IsNullOrEmpty(group)) ? (a.id != -1) : (a.no_group == group))
&& ((group.Equals("990") || (group == string.Empty)) ? (!a.displaylocal.HasValue || a.displaylocal.Value == false) : (a.id != -1))
&& ((a.begindate.HasValue ? DateTime.Now >= a.begindate.Value : a.id != -1) &&
    (a.enddate.HasValue ? DateTime.Now <= a.enddate.Value : a.id != -1))
&& ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(excludeManifestatie)) ? (a.id != -1) : (a.type_manifestation != excludeManifestatie))
```

NEW/BETTER WAY to WRITE:

**QUERY 2:**

```
   var query = dc.agenda.AsQueryable();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(group))
    query = query.Where(a => a.no_group == group);
if (group.Equals("990") || group.Equals(string.Empty))
    if ((query.Where(a => a.displaylocal.HasValue))) //Gives ERROR
        query = query.Where(a => a.displaylocal >= DateTime.Now);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(excludeManifestatie))
    query = query.Where(a => a.type_manifestation != excludeManifestatie);
if (query.Where(a => a.begindate.HasValue)) //Gives ERROR
    query = query.Where(a => a.begindate <= DateTime.Now);
if ((query.Where(a => a.enddate.HasValue))) //Gives ERROR
    query = query.Where(a => a.enddate >= DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: @Answerers: **Please** stop posting nonsense that changes the `if(where)` part to something like `if(any/count/singleordefault)`, because that is something else completely. Please read his question and especially his original query!

Comment: @Daniel you r right we sure missed something in the question but that something was probably way in the right corner:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it like this. If you want to include a condition based on data in each individual row, you need to resort to your way. The method I showed you in your last question only works if the condition should be added based on a external parameter. I would use this condition:

```
query = query.Where(a => (a.begindate.HasValue && a.begindate <= DateTime.Now) || 
                         !a.begindate.HasValue);
```

Your complete code looks like this:

```
var query = dc.agenda.AsQueryable();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(group))
    query = query.Where(a => a.no_group == group);
if (group.Equals("990") || group.Equals(string.Empty))
    query = query.Where(a => (a.displaylocal.HasValue && a.displaylocal >= DateTime.Now) || 
        !a.displaylocal.HasValue);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(excludeManifestatie))
    query = query.Where(a => a.type_manifestation != excludeManifestatie);
query = query.Where(a => (a.begindate.HasValue && a.begindate <= DateTime.Now) || 
                         !a.begindate.HasValue);
query = query.Where(a => (a.enddate.HasValue && a.enddate >= DateTime.Now) || 
                         !a.enddate.HasValue);
```

Comment: I agree with this solution and your comments. All other get -1 from me.

Comment: it works like a machine, so thanks so much again. I compared both  queries and gives both 32 records. Could you just please explain why you add || !a.begindate.HasValue) and || !a.enddate.HasValue); statemetns. I mean when I remove the || !a.begindate.hasvalue I get less records, so that means it should be there. If I read the whole line it says get all records which has beginddate not null and begindate less than today's date OR give all records which 
begindate doens't have a value.. Just a small clarification needed on this statement please?

Comment: @mesut: Sure. The reason is the follow: You only want to check for the date, if it is set, hence the check for `HasValue`. Now `(a.begindate.HasValue && a.begindate <= DateTime.Now)` returns true, if (a) the date is set and (b) it is less or equal to now. You also want to have all records that don't have a date set. However, `(a.begindate.HasValue && a.begindate <= DateTime.Now)` returns false, if the date is not set, because `a.begindate.HasValue` is false. To also return the records that don't have a date set, I added the part with `!a.begindate.HasValue`

Comment: In other words, it asks the following: "Return all records *that have a date set and that date is less than or equal to now* OR **that have no date set at all**." (Bold and italic to emphasize the two different parts of the request)

Answer (score 1):

It's not when you use `HasValue`, it's when you use `Where` as a condition.

If you want to check if there are *any* elements that conform to the `HasValue` condition, you should use `Any` instead of `Where`:

```
if (query.Any(a => a.begindate.HasValue))
```

Comment: Really, why are all of you posting such nonsense? That's something else completely

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: because of the `//Gives ERROR` comments.

Comment: And? Sure it gives an error, because it is invalid. Your answer and the answer of all others show that you didn't read his question, because your answers are semantically different from what he tries to achieve. And what he tries to achieve is stated clearly in his question in the first query!

Answer (score -2):

try changing from

```
query = query.Where(a => a.no_group == group);
```

to

```
query = query.SingleOrDefault(a => a.no_group == group);
```